Zeroes of a function
Let be $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. If $\lim_{x\to 3} f(x)=13$ and the graph of $f$ intersects the $y$-axis in $(0,-3)$, can we say that $f$ admits at least one point $x_0\in [0,3]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$?
My answer: Yes, because of the zeroes theorem. $f$ is continuous by hypothesis and $f(0)f(3)<0$ because $f(13)>0$ for sign permanence theorem.
I'm not really sure about the fact $f(13)>0$ beacause sign permanence theorem says nothing about the point $x=13$. Any clarifications?

Thinking about it a bit more, there's actually no reason why it should be $f(13)>0$. The existence of a neighborhood of $3$ in which $f$ agrees with the sign of $13$ does not guarantee me anything about $f(13)$. Right? So I can't conclude with these hypotheses?

$f(13)$ can be negative. Just use the fact that $f(x)>0$ for $x <3$ close enough to $3$

$f(0)<0$ and $f(3)>0$ so you can apply the intermediate value theorem on the interval $[0,3]$

@SineoftheTime It's a quicker way thanks!!

There's no reason to believe $f(13)>0$. Instead, note that $f(0)<0$ and $f(3)=\lim_{x\to 3}f(x)=13>0$. Conclude applying the intermediate value theorem.

Yes, I believe you can.
We can certainly find a (small enough) interval around 3 where $f$ is positive. This is a general result about continuous functions and follows rather straightforwardly from $\delta$-$\varepsilon$.
Then, applying the Intermediate Value Theorem and taking some point in that interval  as an endpoint, there must be a zero in the interval.
I hope this is helpful!
